# Can both monsters in Tokyo yield at the same time after an attack?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In a 5- or 6-player game of King of Tokyo, there are two spaces in Tokyo: the city, and Tokyo Bay. Normally, if a monster is inside Tokyo, and a monster outside Tokyo attacks, the monster in Tokyo has the option to leave Tokyo, yielding to the outside monster.

How does this change if there are two monsters in Tokyo? If a monster outside Tokyo attacks while there are two monsters in Tokyo, can both monsters yield, leaving Tokyo Bay empty? Or is one of the monsters forced to stay behind and take another beating before they can leave?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.** From the [rulebook](http://www.iellogames.com/download/KOT-US-Rules-low.pdf):

> If the monster in Tokyo Bay is attacked it can choose to abandon Tokyo Bay. In this case the monster that attacked must move in unless it is moving into Tokyo City, in which case Tokyo Bay becomes temporarily unoccupied.

If both monsters yield, as this indicates, the attacker would move into Tokyo City and Tokyo Bay would become temporarily unoccupied.